# Convert Rows to Columns in multiple Rows in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this

```
CREATE table #yourtable
([Id] int, [Value] varchar(16), [ColumnName] varchar(13), [RecId] varchar(5));

INSERT INTO #yourtable
([Id], [Value], [ColumnName], [RecId])
VALUES
(1, 'John', 'FirstName', '1'),
(2, '2.4', 'Amount', '1'),
(3, 'ZH1E4A', 'PostalCode', '1'),
(4, 'Fork', 'LastName', '1'),
(5, '857685', 'AccountNumber', '1'),
(6, 'Bill', 'FirstName', '2'),
(7, '4.2', 'Amount', '2'),
(8, '48122', 'PostalCode', '2'),
(9, 'White', 'LastName', '2'),
(10, '129845', 'AccountNumber', '2');
```

and i need to have two rows like this

[image]

We need an efficiently mode because I have a lot of rows. Thanks for help.

Comment: Show us what you tried thus far.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`PIVOT`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) for this:

```
SELECT [FirstName], [Amount], [PostalCode], 
       [LastName], [AccountNumber]
FROM (
   SELECT RecId, Value, ColumnName
   FROM #yourtable) AS src
PIVOT (
   MAX(Value) FOR ColumnName IN ([FirstName], [Amount], [PostalCode], 
                                 [LastName], [AccountNumber])) AS pvt
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method is using a crosstab or conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT  
      MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnName = 'FirstName' THEN Value END) AS [FirstName]
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnName = 'Amount' THEN Value END) AS [Amount]
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnName = 'PostalCode' THEN Value END) AS [PostalCode]
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnName = 'LastName' THEN Value END) AS [LastName]
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnName = 'AccountNumber' THEN Value END) AS [AccountNumber]
FROM #yourtable
GROUP BY RecId;
```

However, if you have unknown number of `ColumnName`s, you should do it dynamically:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @sql =
'SELECT ' + CHAR(10) +
(SELECT STUFF((SELECT
'   , MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnName = ''' + ColumnName + ''' THEN Value END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(ColumnName) + CHAR(10)
FROM #yourtable
GROUP BY ColumnName
ORDER BY MIN(Id)
FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 2, '')) +
'FROM #yourtable
GROUP BY RecId;';

PRINT (@sql);
EXEC (@sql);
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/500943)</kbd>

Reference:

- [Cross Tabs and Pivots, Part 2 - Dynamic Cross Tabs](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/)  by Jeff Moden